# I am facing rails validation issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have user model and user has country dropdown and Nationality id in signup form. so when user select xx country then the 4th and 5th digit of nationality id must be "78".And xx country id in database is 21. Using devise for authentication but i need this try of validation. so kindly help me to figure out this issue.

Controller

```
    def create

        build_resource(sign_up_params)


          if params[:user][:country_id] == 21
            if params[:user][:nationality_id][4..5] != "78"
              flash[:error] = "The nationality_id is invalid!"
            end
end

        if resource.save
          sign_out resource
          reset_session
          flash[:heading] = "Thank you for registering with us!"
          flash[:message] = "Please confirm your email address through the email sent to your account."
        else
          clean_up_passwords resource
          set_minimum_password_length
          respond_with resource
        end

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to put the validation in the controller action that the fields belong to.

Comment: i have added the code for controller, please have a look

Comment: Is the nationality_id unique to every user? Is there a method that appends the 78 onto the nationality?